# CSS to increase svg font size custom

Tags: css, svg

I am working with a svg element as follows and I am using `css` to control the font-size of the `svg` text.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">


    <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect>
    <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1160" height="600" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>

    <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">
        <g class="yAxis">
            <g class="yAxisLeft" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end">
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,411.7647058823529)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 13.1462 0)" text-anchor="middle">20%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,223.52941176470583)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 13.1462 0)" text-anchor="middle">40%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,35.29411764705883)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" text-anchor="middle" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 12.3462 0)">60%</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

However, when I increase the `font-size`, e.g.

```
.tick>text{
font-size: xx-large;
}
```

it changes to this

[image: result]

Is there anyway I can have the `font-size` increased, yet the text would be aligned to the `green` line? like below
[image: Q]

As an alternative, I tried following

```css
.tick>text{
    transform-origin: left;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform: scaleY(2.5);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">


    <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect>
    <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1160" height="600" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>

    <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">
        <g class="yAxis">
            <g class="yAxisLeft" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end">
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,411.7647058823529)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 13.1462 0)" text-anchor="middle">20%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,223.52941176470583)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 13.1462 0)" text-anchor="middle">40%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,35.29411764705883)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="-3" dy="0.32em" text-anchor="middle" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 12.3462 0)">60%</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

```
.tick>text{
    transform-origin: left;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform: scaleY(2.5);
}
```

but it is not applying the scaling from the desired origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try positioning your test at `x="0"` instead of `x="-3"`.
Also remove the `transform` and `test-anchor="middle/end"` attributes.

```css
.tick>text{
    transform-origin: left;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform: scaleY(2.5);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">


    <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect>
    <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1160" height="600" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>

    <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">
        <g class="yAxis">
            <g class="yAxisLeft" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif">
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,411.7647058823529)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="0" dy="0.32em">20%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,223.52941176470583)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="0" dy="0.32em">40%</text>
                </g>
                <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,35.29411764705883)">
                    <line stroke="currentColor" x2="1160"></line>
                    <text fill="currentColor" x="0" dy="0.32em">60%</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```